# A director will tell us how she chooses/chose the actors

Tags: grammar, verbs

(An excerpt from an English book's audio script)
Situation: You and other students will meet a director of a play.

> "We're going to meet a director. She'll describe the whole process of producing a play, including how she **chose** the actor."

Why is it that "**chose**" was selected as the grammatical verb here instead of "**chooses**" (present simple=fact), which I believe is the one that should be used instead.

Comment: Your "Let's say" suggests that this is a hypothetical, but "Why is ity that 'chose' was chosen" suggests that this is something which was actually said. Which is it?

Comment: Thx for the correction, I thought this won't be spotted. I'm editing it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either is fine.  It depends on the exact circumstances.

As your example is written, using "chose" (past tense), this is the implied sequence of events:

> 1. You (the audience) are going to meet a director
> 2. This director is going to describe how to produce a play, **using, as a model, a play she already produced.**
> 3. As part of this description, the director will include how she **chose** the actor for this play.

Using "chooses" (present tense), the sequence is slightly different:

> 1. You (the audience) are going to meet a director
> 2. This director is going to describe how to produce a play, **using, as a model, a hypothetical future production.**
> 3. As part of this description, the director will include how she **chooses** an actor for this play.

Admittedly, it's a bit tricky to spot the difference in nuance implied by the verb shift, but this is to be expected when learning a language at a more advanced level.

Answer (score 1):

> We're going to meet a director. She'll describe the whole process of producing a play, including how she chose the actor.

I believe whoever wrote this either made a mistake *or* it could also mean that the director is going to talk about a specific play and how she chose the actor, assuming for this play the actor was already chosen in the past.